# How to return the order statistic of a whole array?

Tags: python

I have searched the web but could not find a solution. If I have an array, let's say:

```
x=[17, 1, 2, 7, 8, 5, 27, 29]
```

I am searching for an easy way such that a vector of order statistics, i.e.

```
y=[6, 1, 2, 4, 5, 3, 7, 8]
```

is returned. Of course it can also be (typical for python) indexed starting with zero; Additinally, it would be perfect if there are two or more entries of the same value like:

```
x=[17, 1, 2, 1, 8, 5, 27, 29]
```

That we have a result like this:

```
y=[6, 2, 3, 2, 5, 4, 7, 8]
```

Basically, since I dont have LaTeX, I want as a result:

"#numbers smaller or equal this number"; Therefore either entry, that is one has two numbers which are smaller or equal one and therefore the desired entry would be 2;

Comment: the best way is to initially sort the array (and keep the original index as well). Then simply traverse the sorteed array and construct a new array in each associated index has the number of items before that position in the sorted array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `sorted`:

```
s = sorted(x)
[s.index(i) + 1 for i in x]
```

Output:

```
[6, 1, 2, 4, 5, 3, 7, 8]
```

*Note that index originally starts with 0, thus `+1` is slightly unconventional, which may raise error later if you were to use it back to find the original value.*

Comment: It may be best to presort the array as otherwise you are resorting `x` `len(x)` times.

Comment: Oh that is true, I'll try to figure that out on my own and also, just for fun, run a comparison of execution time

Comment: @jhansen ah rookie mistake ;) thanks for pointing out. I will edit shortly

Comment: you can optionally remove the .index call as well since it is not efficient. Instead you could sort an array or index=>value in same time and have the original index ready